# .NET C# Multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading

Question about threading to satisfy my curiosity...

Let's say I have static variable _status (ProgressStatus) and many threads are reading from this. 
To update this static variable I use an immutable object ProgressStatus, create a new instance and then swap out the reference.

```
var status = new ProgressStatus (50, "Working on it"); //plus many more fields in constructor

lock (_statusLocker) _status = status; // Very brief lock
```

Here's the reader code

```
public GetProgressStatus () {

     var status = new ProgressStatus (_status.ID, _status.Description); 
     return status }
```

What's the worst that could happen if I don't apply the lock?

Comment: It's important for you to show us the reader code as well. Btw, the immutability of the *object* doesn't solve everything, nor does the fact that assigning a reference is atomic. `Console.WriteLine(status.Progress + ", " + status.Text)` could *still* produce something like `"50, Complete"` if the *reference* is changed by another thread in the middle of the operation. I guess you'll have to decide if that sort of inconsistency is acceptable.

Comment: Good point. As I wrote the reader code I realised this too - lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible that other threads won't see the new value.

Indeed, unless they're locking too, it's *still* possible that they won't see the new value.

Even though the reference will updated atomically (i.e. it'll never be some value which is a mixture of the old and new values), that says nothing about when the change becomes visible to other threads - or when other threads will even bother checking. (For example, one thread may have cached the value in a register, and without any indication that the thread *needs* to check main memory, it may not do so.)

It's possible that by declaring the variable as `volatile` you'll avoid this - but I've stopped believing that I understand exactly what `volatile` means, to be honest.

Using a lock consistently when working with shared mutable data (reading *or* writing) makes this problem go away due to the semantics of locking. Doing it in a lock-free and guaranteed-correct way involves considerably deeper understanding of what's going on. (Note that it's the *variable* which is mutable here, even if the object it refers to isn't.)

Comment: So true about volatile. Spent countless of hours trying to get a 100% accurate understanding of it, but I'm still not sure I get it.

Comment: I had a look at `volatile` a few days ago (http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/simonc/archive/2010/11/24/95830.aspx), and I couldn't find any documentation on it that wasn't contradictory or misleading. In particular, the CLR docs on the `volatile.` prefix seem to be completely different to what the C# spec says on `volatile`. It would be nice to get the 'official' view from a Microsoft CLR person at some point...

Comment: @thecoop: Yeah. I used to go with the idea that a write to a volatile variable immediately went to main memory, and a read always came from main memory, effectively. I don't think it's that simple, and I get very confused :( Best left to the experts, IMO.

Comment: In my code, I'm actually trying to read from a Dictionary object. So potentially my update code will out the Dictionary object as it's being read (by some internal routines in the dictionary object) , and I guess might yield unexpected results

Comment: @Mark 909: If it's a plain `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` then that's not thread-safe anyway.

Comment: I wouldn't be updating the dictionary. Just creating a new one and swapping it out. Isn't it safe for multiple concurrent reads from the dictionary - I think thats what it says on MSDN

Comment: @Mark: Okay, that's safe in terms of the dictionary itself... which just leaves the issue raised in my answer around whether or not you see the updated variable value.

Comment: The other threads would be periodically reading it and throwing it away. But danger is that it reads one value, then the underlying static is changed then it reads the second value - hence the read is corrupt...? Thanks for you patience with this

Comment: @Mark 909: The read wouldn't be corrupt - it would just refer to the new dictionary. If you want to read multiple values from a single dictionary, you should copy the reference to a local variable and repeatedly read via that.

Comment: In my scenario it's acceptable to use either the old of the new dictionary. So I'm guessing there shouldn't be any problems in not using locks...?

Comment: @Mark 909: If you don't mind the (extremely remote) possibility that you'll never see the new dictionary, that's okay. If you need to guarantee that you'll see the most recent value of the variable, you need some kind of memory barrier.

Comment: Well since the reads will be hammering away continuously and the write will be once a month then I'm guessing it should be ok

Comment: @Mark 909: If the method which is reading the variable returns and then is called again soon after, I strongly suspect you'll be okay. I'm just pointing out that it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

You may get a race condition if your program relies on this value getting updated in a predictable manner.

Here's a good 'lock-free' function:

```
static void LockFreeUpdate<T>(ref T field, Func<T, T> updateFunction)
    where T : class
{
    var spinWait = new SpinWait();
    while (true)
    {
        T snapshot1 = field;
        T calc = updateFunction(snapshot1);
        T snapshot2 = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref field, calc, snapshot1);
        if (snapshot1 == snapshot2) return;
        spinWait.SpinOnce();
    }
}
```

I cant take the credit, I found it on the web

http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_SpinLock_and_SpinWait

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need the lock in this case, since changing a reference is an atomic operation.

Comment: I don't understand why this comment has been marked down, can anyone explain? Seems reasonable to me

Comment: @Mark 909: Because it's incorrect as explained in my comment. Just because the update is atomic doesn't mean the lock (or some other memory barrier) isn't required.

Comment: More specifically, if _status isn't marked volatile, other threads might not see the change in value right away.  I had assumed it was already volatile when I wrote my answer, which is not the most brilliant assumption I've made.  Anyway, it appears that volatile may not even accomplish what it's documented to, as per Jon Skeet's answer.